# First step in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am going to learn Ruby on Rails (ROR) , can any one help me how to write a "hello world" program and How can I run the program.

Comment: Try http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/getting-started/first-rails-app-walkthrough and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the answer....

we need to use the following steps.

1. rails appliaction_name
       - It will create a directory.
         In that directory contains list of files and directories.

   ```
    app        config  doc  log     Rakefile  script  tmp
    components  db     lib  public  README    test    vendor
   ```
2. Change the file mode "777" for public/ log/ and tmp/ file. because the program will write the datas in to the files.
3. ./script/generate controller controller_name

   Then it will create the controller_name.rb (ruby file in app/ directory)
4. Then we can write the codeing in to the app/controllers/controller.rb file.
5. Then we need to call the function from browser.

Thanks................

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to install ruby http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/ .
All your things you have to install you find here http://rubyonrails.org/download
Well, i suggest to start with http://rubyonrails.org/screencasts, the 15 minutes weblog tutorial.

Comment: see the following answer only I asked,

Answer (score 2):

Check out _why's poignant guide to ruby.